# How to design badge model in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to make badge model in google app engine using ndb
i design like this:

```
class Badge(ndb.Model):
    icon = BlobKeyProperty()
    title = StringProperty()


class User(ndb.Model):
    ...
    badges = KeyProperty(Badge, repeated=True)
```

But i have problem but property earning day to model
Example:
User U1 earn badge B1 when 22/03/2014

Comment: It would make sense to be more specific about the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Make badge icons static files. There is no need to store them as blobs.